# How to create a custom theme for QtCreator

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-creator

I would like to create and share a free Qt app for easy creation of custom QtCreator themes. My problem though is not the creation of the app itself, but the format of the **.creatortheme* file.

I have made a copy of the *flat.creatortheme* found under *Tools\QtCreator\share\qtcreator\themes* and since I can't find the names of the variables documented anywhere, I used the trial-and-error approach in order to figure out the meaning of the variables. For the most of them I've succeeded. However for the ones starting with `Timeline_` and `VcsBase_` I can't see any change in the visual appearence for my setup of the IDE (Qt 5.10.0, MSVC 2017, Windows 7).

So if I make that just for myself, that would be enough, but since I would like to share the app with the rest of you, I think I should cover those values as well.

Does anyone have an experience with this?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: hi, any progeress on your app?) qtcreator really lacks theme support functionality now with all these hipster ui IDEs like atom, sublime, vs code etc. qtcreator should catch up, so your app may come in handy

Comment: I've put the issue to the side, but it will come soon.

Comment: good, goodluck with it

Comment: Any news of the app? Since Qt Creator updates to v12.0 my "Flat" theme becomes not so nice and familiar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [source code](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qt-creator/src/libs/utils/theme/theme.h.html) of Qt Creator those are listed in the `Color` enum of the `Theme` class:

```
...
/* Timeline Library */
Timeline_TextColor,
Timeline_BackgroundColor1,
Timeline_BackgroundColor2,
Timeline_DividerColor,
Timeline_HighlightColor,
Timeline_PanelBackgroundColor,
Timeline_PanelHeaderColor,
Timeline_HandleColor,
Timeline_RangeColor,

/* VcsBase Plugin */
VcsBase_FileStatusUnknown_TextColor,
VcsBase_FileAdded_TextColor,
VcsBase_FileModified_TextColor,
VcsBase_FileDeleted_TextColor,
VcsBase_FileRenamed_TextColor,
VcsBase_FileUnmerged_TextColor,
...
```

According to the comments, they are used by the *Timeline Library* and the *VcsBase Plugin*.